# Error en PHP con la librería mbstring (mPDF)

Tags: php, linux, php7

Tengo un programa en PHP que lo desarrollaron en windows y funciona bien, pero en Linux (amazon linux 2) manda un error la librería:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: mbstring extension must be
>   loaded in order to run mPDF in
>   /var/www/html/reportes/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php:9493 Stack trace:
>
> #0 /var/www/html/reportes/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(1001): Mpdf\Mpdf->_dochecks()
>
> #1 /var/www/html/reportes/pdf.php(34): Mpdf\Mpdf->__construct(Array)
>
> #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/reportes/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php on line 9493

Ya intente varias soluciones pero sin éxito

La librería esta instalada correctamente

```
php -v
PHP 7.2.22 (cli) (built: Sep 24 2019 20:09:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

php -m
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Comment: Agrega un poco de tu codigo que corresponda con el programa para saber si el problema surge desde ahi.

Comment: Esta es las linea 33 a 39 y el error dice que es la 34: 
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
 'mode' => 'utf-8',
 'format' => [190, 236],
 'margin-top' => 0,
 'margin-header' => 0

]);

Answer (score 1):

Los módulos están presentes en la instalación, pero el mensaje indica que no están activados. Esto se hace en el archivo `php.ini` que se carga en tiempo de ejecución. Para determinar cuál es el archivo `php.ini` que se está usando, se crea un script .php con la función `phpinfo()` en la aplicación (es posible e incluso común que el PHP interactivo, el integrado en Apache o el separado (fpm) en Apache/Nginx usen distintos archivos).

Esa función también indica en cuáles directorios se buscan archivos .ini adicionales. La página resultante debería mostrar una sección dedicada al módulo `mbstring` si está realmente activo. De no ser así, habría que asegurarse que está correctamente activado en el archivo de configuración usado.

La directiva en el archivo sería:

```
extension=mbstring.so
```

y podría estar comentada con un punto y coma `;`. Habría que descomentarla, reiniciar el servidor web/php, y consultar de nuevo el script que tiene el `phpinfo()` para verificar que se activó.

Comment: Gracias, puse en el php.ini extension=mbstring y reincide apache sudo systemctl restart httpd, sin éxito, sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje

Comment: Con respecto a los temas php.ini que despliega phpinfo() estas son: /etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini, /etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini, /etc/php.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini, /etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini, /etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini

Que debo buscar?

Comment: Trate de activar el modulo con estos comandos 
$ sudo yum update -y
$ sudo yum install -y php-gd
$ sudo reboot
$ sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
$ sudo systemctl restart http

y ahora me sale Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /var/www/html/reportes/Modelos/Database.php on line 29

y el codigo es: // Sends the query to the connection
    public function Query($sql) {
        $this->_result = $this->_link->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($this->_result));
        $this->_numRows = mysqli_num_rows($this->_result);
    }

Comment: Creo que debe ser` extension=mbstring.so` (mi error, ya corregí la respuesta), además de que esa librería debería instalarse con `yum install php-mbstring`. Hay que identificar cuál es el php.ini principal en la salida del phpinfo(), la lista solo indica los adicionales. Si el php está integrado reiniciar el httpd; con el php-fpm basta con reiniciar éste para aplicar cambios.

Comment: En rigor, nuevas preguntas deben hacerse de manera separada y no en comentarios, pero observo que la función query de mysqli devuelve false en `$this->_result` en caso de error y `mysqli_error()` pide el enlace de la conexión, por eso no lo acepta; la solución para esto es usar el enlace: `...or die(mysqli_error($this->_link));` o mejor aún llamar directamente al indicador de error del objeto mysqli: `...or die($this->_link->error);`.